# Source(s) that Rashi's daughters gave shiur in gemara to men, from behind a mehitza or curtain?

Tags: torah-study, women, rashi

Rabbi Breitowitz says so in a shiur here, starting at 1:19:40, https://podcasts.ohr.edu/episode/60

He says "It is brought down in some mekoros..." Anyone know the mekoros?

Comment: It's mentioned [here](https://asif.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8.pdf) too without a source.

Comment: It’s brought down about the grandmother of the Maharsha https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol14Issue3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in Sevuvei Rav Psachya of Regensberg that Rav Shmuel Halevi, a Rosh Yeshiva in Bagdad had an only daughter who was an expert in Chumash and Talmud. She would deliver lectures behind a window. The students would sit outside, unable to see her.

The Maharshal in ש׳׳ת הערות כט states his grandmother Rebbetzin Miriam directed a yeshiva for many years. Sitting behind a curtain she would lecture to advanced students. She is a descendent of Rashi but not a daughter....

The above sourced from Mekor Baruch

As you can see although very rare, I suppose if a woman would teach Torah it was self understood to be done with modesty. So is it possible, that if Rashi's daughters taught Torah it might be behind a curtain? I don't know of a source though.